# Why $u = v \Rightarrow u + w = v + w$ for all $u,v,w$ in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I think the question is simple, but I'm a bit confused with proving the following rule for any $u,v,w$ in a vector space $V$ (with the usual 8 axioms for vector spaces, as in it's [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space)):
$$
u = v \Rightarrow u+w = v+w
$$
I think it's related to $"="$ being a binary relation, but I don't know where to start to prove it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But why can I sum things both sides?

Comment: @DietrichBurde This has nothing to do with being Abelian. This is true just because $+$ is a function.

Comment: I think because vector space is an algebra.

Comment: See wikipedia article on algebra structure or algebra over field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is purely because $+$ is a function *and* because $u=v$ implies $(u,w)=(v,w)$. Let $f:X\to Z$ be a function and $x=y$. Then $f(x)=f(y)$.

The property is also known as $+$ being **well defined**. Does this help?

Comment: Just use the same argument with the function $f_w(x) = x + w$.

Comment: The key phrase here is "well defined."  (+1)

Comment: @marshalcraft no algebraic structure is relevant here. Well defined means exactly that the definition is correct and the result is a function. So in a sense, yeah, it means consistent.

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what your talking about then, I apologize ignore these comments. Will delte.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that this is about the meaning of "$=$". The assertion $u=v$ means essentially that $u$ and $v$ are different names for the same object. So of course $u+w = v+w$.

This will be true whenever "$+$" makes sense, and has nothing to do with vector spaces.

Answer (score 2):

A fundamental property of equality is that whenever $x=y$ holds, and you have some true statement involving $x$, then you can replace some or all of the occurrences of $x$ with $y$, and get another true statement. This doesn't depend on whether you look at statements in set theory, group theory, field theory, linear algebra, analysis or whatever other theory you can or cannot think of.

So in your case, if you know that $u=v$, then you can take the fact that $u+w=u+w$ (this is another fundamental property of equality: Anything is equivalent to itself) and replace the second $u$ with $v$ to get $u+w=v+w$.

Note that to be able to do this replacement, you do *not* need to know that $u$, $v$ and $w$ are vectors, or what $+$ does (other than that it is a well-defined operation), or whatever else. All you need to know is that expressions of the form $x+y$ make sense and describe an object in whatever theory you are looking at.

Comment: I like this argument. Your thought flow is completely explained (except possibly for something about not knowing about what "+" means and swapping such variables is well formed and basically just atomic statements and basic axioms of the logical system). All of which is not necessary to convince me. So I thought it was great answer, but now I wonder -that if we can deduce the above property as a logical principle formed from our "signature" and axioms, as well perhaps any kind of function(the very short other answre), what is the minimal way to describe it?

Comment: So like $x = y$ then $x\land w = y \land w$ as well as $ x \cup w = y \cup w$ and anything with an equivalence relation and "nice" functions has this property.

Comment: @marshalcraft: No, an equivalence relation does not suffice. It's exactly what differentiates equality from a general equivalence relation.

Comment: Well the property holds with equivilance relation and equivilance class, no? from the perspective of the nice function?

Comment: An equivalence relation on the original set reduces to an equality on the equivalence classes, and therefore for operations on *equivalence classes* you can do it. This restriction is important, because not all operations on the base set need to lead to equivalent operations on the equivalence classes. The best example being the equivalence classes modulo a composite number, and division.

Comment: Well the situation seems certainly more complex. Thanks for your answer and comments.